# is there a plugin for custom video capture interface for Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build a Vine-like app using the Ionic Framework.  I've got the mediaCapture plugin working but it uses the native camera functionality.  The user has to leave me app to record video using the native interface and then return to my app.  How can add a button and camera controls within my app like Vine or Instagram?

Comment: do you find something? i'm looking into the same. Kinda touch (record) untouch (pause)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Camera plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera).
This plugin defines a global navigator.camera object, which provides an API for taking pictures and for choosing images from the system's image library.

If you want to get video file type of gallery, you can use mediaType, like this:

```
Camera.MediaType = {
    PICTURE: 0,    // allow selection of still pictures only. DEFAULT. Will return format specified via DestinationType
    VIDEO: 1,      // allow selection of video only, WILL ALWAYS RETURN FILE_URI
    ALLMEDIA : 2   // allow selection from all media types
};
```